# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework : adding a record to a table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, boolean

I have created a table via EF code first migration called errands.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace errandomWeb.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<errands> errandList { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

This is further defined in my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace errandomWeb.Models
{
    public class errands
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Hometown { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Posted")]
        public DateTime DateTimePosted { get; set; }
        public string LatitudePosted { get; set; }
        public string LongitudePosted { get; set; }
        public string LocationPosted { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Don't be shy and put some text, but keep it short.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Don't be shy and put some text, but keep it short.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "If you don't find your category, go with 'Other'")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "If you don't find your subcategory, go with 'Other'")]
        public string SubCategory { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Come on.. people need to know that.")]
        [StringLength(999, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Come on.. people need to know that.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You don't have to give us your exact address, but people need to know where work needs to get done...")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "As Soon As Possible")]
        public bool ASAP { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date & Time")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "When can the work be started?")]
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "It's important to give a rough idea of how long this work will take.")]
        [Display(Name = "Estimated Effort (h)")]
        public string DurationInHours { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Until when will the work have to be done the latest?")]
        [Display(Name = "End Date & Time")]
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "That one has quite an impact on the amount.")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Do you think somebody would do the job for free?")]
        public string Offering { get; set; }
        public string errandFee { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Total Amount")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string errandTax { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Yup, we want to know that too.")]
        [Display(Name = "Payment Method")]
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to post 'errands', once posted, I would send them to a preview and from there I'd offer to edit (which is essentially going back to a similar view as composing the errand) or publish it, which would mean changing the `Published` bool from standard false to true.

I've accomplished that by just using the following controller code:

```
// GET: PostErrand
public ActionResult PostErrand()
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var model = new PostErrandViewModel
            {
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = UserManager.FindById(userID).FirstName,
                Email = UserManager.FindById(userID).Email,
                Phone = UserManager.FindById(userID).PhoneNumber,
                Location = UserManager.FindById(userID).Hometown
                //Rating = 
            };

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    ViewBag.category = db.CategoryList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Category,
                Value = m.Category
            }).ToList();
    ViewBag.subcategory = db.SubCategoryList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.SubCategory,
                Value = m.SubCategory
            }).ToList();
    ViewBag.currency = db.CurrencyList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Currency,
                Value = m.Currency
            }).ToList();
    ViewBag.paymentmethod = db.PaymentMethodList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.PaymentMethod,
                Value = m.PaymentMethod
            }).ToList();

    var Loaded = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "PostErrand_Loaded",
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            };

    DB.UserActivityList.Add(Loaded);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}

// POST: PostErrand
public ActionResult PostErrandToDB([Bind(Exclude = "Picture")]errands model)
{
    string pictureFile = Request.Form["postErrandCroppedPicture"];
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pictureFile);
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var errand = new errands
            {
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = UserManager.FindById(userId).FirstName,
                Email = UserManager.FindById(userId).Email,
                Phone = UserManager.FindById(userId).PhoneNumber,
                Hometown = UserManager.FindById(userId).Hometown,
                Rating = model.Rating,
                Category = model.Category,
                SubCategory = model.SubCategory,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                Location = model.Location,
                ASAP = model.ASAP,
                StartDateTime = model.StartDateTime,
                DurationInHours = model.DurationInHours,
                EndDateTime = model.EndDateTime,
                DateTimePosted = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
                Currency = model.Currency,
                Offering = model.Offering,
                Price = model.Price,
                errandTax = model.errandTax,
                PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod,
                LatitudePosted = model.LatitudePosted,
                LongitudePosted = model.LongitudePosted,
                LocationPosted = model.LocationPosted,
                Published = false
            };

    if (imageBytes.Length > 2) 
    {
        errand.Picture = imageBytes;
    }

    DB.errandList.Add(errand);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    var Success = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "PostErrand_Success",
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                ActivityLatitude = model.LatitudePosted,
                ActivityLongitude = model.LongitudePosted,
                ActivityLocation = model.LocationPosted
            };

    DB.UserActivityList.Add(Success);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("errandPreview");
}

// GET: errandPreview
public ActionResult errandPreview()
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var errand = DB.errandList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                              .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTimePosted)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

    var model = new errands
            {
                ID = errand.ID,
                Title = errand.Title,
                Category = errand.Category,
                SubCategory = errand.SubCategory,
                Picture = errand.Picture,
                Description = errand.Description,
                Location = errand.Location,
                ASAP = errand.ASAP,
                StartDateTime = errand.StartDateTime,
                EndDateTime = errand.EndDateTime,
                DurationInHours = errand.DurationInHours,
                DateTimePosted = errand.DateTimePosted,
                PaymentMethod = errand.PaymentMethod,
                Currency = errand.Currency,
                Offering = errand.Offering,
                Price = errand.Price,
                FirstName = errand.FirstName,
                Rating = errand.Rating
            };

    var Loaded = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "ErrandPreview_Loaded",
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            };

    DB.UserActivityList.Add(Loaded);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    return View(model);
}

public FileContentResult errandPicture()
{
    String userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var errand = DB.errandList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                              .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTimePosted)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

    if (errand.Picture == null)
    {
        string defaultPicture = Server.MapPath("/Content/errandom_logo_sm.png");
        byte[] imageData = null;

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(defaultPicture);
        long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(defaultPicture, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);

        return File(imageData, "image/png");
    }
    else
    {
        return new FileContentResult(errand.Picture, "image/jpeg");
    }
}

// GET: EditErrand
public ActionResult EditErrand()
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var errand = DB.errandList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                              .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTimePosted)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

    var model = new errands
            {
                ID = errand.ID,
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = UserManager.FindById(userID).FirstName,
                Email = UserManager.FindById(userID).Email,
                Phone = UserManager.FindById(userID).PhoneNumber,
                //Rating = 

                Title = errand.Title,
                Category = errand.Category,
                SubCategory = errand.SubCategory,
                Picture = errand.Picture,
                Description = errand.Description,
                Location = errand.Location,
                ASAP = errand.ASAP,
                StartDateTime = errand.StartDateTime,
                EndDateTime = errand.EndDateTime,
                DurationInHours = errand.DurationInHours,
                DateTimePosted = errand.DateTimePosted,
                PaymentMethod = errand.PaymentMethod,
                Currency = errand.Currency,
                Offering = errand.Offering,
                Price = errand.Price,
                Rating = errand.Rating
            };

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    ViewBag.categorySelected = db.CategoryList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Category,
                Value = m.Category
            }).ToList();

    ViewBag.subcategorySelected = db.SubCategoryList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.SubCategory,
                Value = m.SubCategory
            }).ToList();

    ViewBag.currencySelected = db.CurrencyList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.Currency,
                Value = m.Currency
            }).ToList();

    ViewBag.paymentmethodSelected = db.PaymentMethodList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.PaymentMethod,
                Value = m.PaymentMethod
            }).ToList();

    var Loaded = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "EditErrand_Loaded",
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            };

    DB.UserActivityList.Add(Loaded);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    return View(model);
}

// POST: EditErrand
public ActionResult UpdateErrand([Bind(Exclude = "Picture")]errands model)
{
    string newPic = Request.Form["editErrandCroppedPicture"];
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(newPic);

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var errand = new errands
            {
                ID = model.ID,
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = UserManager.FindById(userId).FirstName,
                Email = UserManager.FindById(userId).Email,
                Phone = UserManager.FindById(userId).PhoneNumber,
                Hometown = UserManager.FindById(userId).Hometown,
                Rating = model.Rating,
                Category = model.Category,
                SubCategory = model.SubCategory,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                Location = model.Location,
                ASAP = model.ASAP,
                StartDateTime = model.StartDateTime,
                DurationInHours = model.DurationInHours,
                EndDateTime = model.EndDateTime,
                DateTimePosted = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
                Currency = model.Currency,
                Offering = model.Offering,
                Price = model.Price,
                errandTax = model.errandTax,
                PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod,
                LatitudePosted = model.LatitudePosted,
                LongitudePosted = model.LongitudePosted,
                LocationPosted = model.LocationPosted,
                UserActivityLatitude = model.LatitudePosted,
                UserActivityLongitude = model.LongitudePosted,
                UserActivityLocation = model.LocationPosted,
                Published = false
            };

    if (imageBytes.Length > 2)
    {
        errand.Picture = imageBytes;
    }

    DB.Entry(errand).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DB.SaveChanges();

    var Success = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "EditErrand_Success",
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                ActivityLatitude = model.UserActivityLatitude,
                ActivityLongitude = model.UserActivityLongitude,
                ActivityLocation = model.UserActivityLocation
            };
            DB.UserActivityList.Add(Success);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("errandPreview");
  }

  // POST: errandPreview
  public ActionResult ConfirmErrand([Bind(Exclude = "Picture")]errands model)
  {
      var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

      var errand = new errands
            {
                ID = model.ID,
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FirstName = UserManager.FindById(userId).FirstName,
                Email = UserManager.FindById(userId).Email,
                Phone = UserManager.FindById(userId).PhoneNumber,
                Hometown = UserManager.FindById(userId).Hometown,
                Rating = model.Rating,
                Category = model.Category,
                SubCategory = model.SubCategory,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                Location = model.Location,
                ASAP = model.ASAP,
                StartDateTime = model.StartDateTime,
                DurationInHours = model.DurationInHours,
                EndDateTime = model.EndDateTime,
                DateTimePosted = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime(),
                Currency = model.Currency,
                Offering = model.Offering,
                Price = model.Price,
                errandTax = model.errandTax,
                PaymentMethod = model.PaymentMethod,
                LatitudePosted = model.LatitudePosted,
                LongitudePosted = model.LongitudePosted,
                LocationPosted = model.LocationPosted,
                UserActivityLatitude = model.LatitudePosted,
                UserActivityLongitude = model.LongitudePosted,
                UserActivityLocation = model.LocationPosted,
                Published = true
            };

      DB.Entry(errand).State = EntityState.Modified;
      DB.SaveChanges();

      var Success = new UserActivities
            {
                ActivityName = "errandPreview_Success",
                UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                ActivityTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                ActivityLatitude = model.UserActivityLatitude,
                ActivityLongitude = model.UserActivityLongitude,
                ActivityLocation = model.UserActivityLocation
            };

      DB.UserActivityList.Add(Success);
      DB.SaveChanges();

      return RedirectToAction("PostErrand");
}
```

Now I am running into multiple issues and I have been told that I am using the Data Model instead of a View Model, but whenever I try to use a view model (simply replacing errands with a View Model containing the requisite values) it would not work with the code above.

Some of the issues I run into are:

1. picture is always updated, even when no new value is added, it would override/delete the existing one
2. instead of changing the record, the code would add a new one (which is not the goal)
3. change of bool 'Published' does not work at all - it's just being ignored

Comment: Manually modifying the entity state is a code smell, in my opinion. In your edit method you should be loading the record from the context, then updating each field directly on that instance. I'm not sure what you mean when you say the "published" value is being ignored. In which action is it being ignored?

Comment: Thx @NickCoad. Unfortunately this is the only way I know how to do it. Would you mind to provide an example?